# How to access object not stored in variable

Tags: java

I have this method that I pass a newly created object into

```
foo(new WebObject());
```

How do I get access to the WebObject to use in another object? In other words where do newly created objects reference go?

Comment: you need a reference to the object.

Comment: If it's not stored in a variable...you're kind of out of luck.  It would make your life **far easier** to have a reference for it.

Comment: That reference is going into the `foo()` method.  The only way you're going to get it is if `foo()` stored it somewhere and you can access that variable.

Comment: Is there some common object pool that I can pluck it out of?

Comment: If what youre asking was possible, wouldn't it undermine garbage collection?

Comment: @user758114 - There are not, at least not in the way you are thinking of.

Comment: I see how that would undermine gc.

Comment: @user758114 I notice you just upvoted my answer - just as a reminder, if one of the answers answers your question, click the checkmark to the left of that post, just under the voting arrows. This flags the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Invictus there is a timelimit before you can accept an answer; I believe it is 15 minutes which has only just expired

Comment: @RichardTingle Huh. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Invitus yeah, its to give time for more answers and for the existing answers to be properly considered, here's a link from meta about it;  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer

Comment: I hate to seem obnoxiously reputation-obsessed, but since you appear to understand accepting answers (having done so on your other questions) and are currently active on the site, I'd like to give you a bit of a friendly reminder that you have not yet accepted an answer here, despite it being highly upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you mean - if you mean to say that you want to use it later, after the function call, then you  want to do something like

```
WebObject wObj = new WebObject();
foo (wObj);
WebObject nObj = wObj;
```

If, however, you mean you want to use the object within the foo(WebObject) method, then what you need to do is, within the function, something more along the lines of

```
foo (WebObject obj)
{
  WebObject local = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a variable!

```
WebObject whatever = new WebObject();
foo(whatever);
bar(whatever);
```

Answer (score 1):

as `user2357112` posted you can assign new object to a local variable and pass it via few methods

```
WebObject instance= new WebObject();
foo(instance);
foo2(instance);
System.out.println(instance);
```

but if you're looking something else, you might assign it to a supporting class

```
public class WebObjectKeeper{
    private static WebObject instance=null;

    public static void setWebObject(WebObject obj){
        this.instance=obj;
    }
    public static WebObject getWebObject(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and then you use it in code like:

```
public void myMethod(){
    WebObjectKeeper.setWebObjcet(new WebObject());
    foo(WebObjectKeeper.getWebObject());
    foo2();
}
public void foo2(){
    WebObjectKeeper.getWebObject().executeThisMethod();
    System.out.println("Object = " + WebObjectKeeper.getWebObject());
}
```